# Ansible Get hostname from hosts file

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I want to be able to get the first 8 characters of the first host in a group from a hosts file.  So in the below example I want a variable to be assigned `xx33sx01`.  I know I can use inventory_hostname to get the hosts but it returns all 4 and I only need the first host and only the first 8 characters.

example inventory of Ansible (INI-style):

```
[TEST1]
xx33sx0101.domain.com
xx33sx0102.domain.com
xx33sx0103.domain.com
xx33sx0104.domain.com
```

`ansible-playbook /local_home/scripts/test.yml -i ~/hosts -e "target=TEST1" -K`

Answer (score 3):

To get the first 8 characters of the first hostname in the group, try

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups[target_group][0][:8] }}"
  vars:
    target_group: TEST1
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

- To make the debug task work, the group must be available to the playbook, of course. For example

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups[target_group][0][:8] }}"
```

- [Ordering execution based on inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory) can influence the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  That works perfectly.  This particular script will run against a number of groups from the host file.  Is there a way to use the 'target' instead of hardcoding the group name since the target will change??  For example it could be 'target=TEST1' or 'target=TEST2'.

Comment: You're welcome. Simply put the substitution into the code. I've updated the answer with an example. The details (hosts, vars, run_once ...) would depend on the use-case, of course. Open a new question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you have another issue.

Comment: Perfect solution.  Thank you very much for your time.